# Strange mdadm raid1 uuid behavior

Tags: linux, mdadm, uuid

Command: `# mdadm --detail /dev/md0`,
UUID: `UUID : 75ef0eb7:26381ba8:a00e8abd:98c0de06`

Command: `# ls -lh /dev/disk/by-uuid/`,
UUID: `c016314e-55fc-4a03-b3d2-4d2862cce7cc -> ../../md0`

Why are UUIDs different?

Comment: Relating some more good reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129499/117549